# If I were to weigh all the food and water I take in, and weigh all of the human waste I produced could that be used to determine weight gain or loss?

Tags: diet

As the title says, I am curious if the difference between the total weight of all the food I take in during a week, and all the excrement and urine (and sweat) I release in a week would add up to the total difference in the weight of my person from the start and end of that cycle.

Thanks.

Comment: Try reddit.com/r/askscience.

Comment: So you think the wood that went in the fire would equal the weight of the ash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not the first to wonder that, have a read of [Santorio Santorio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santorio_Santorio) page :-)

To quote Wikipedia:

> For a period of thirty years Santorio weighed himself, everything he
>   ate and drank, as well as his urine and feces. He compared the weight
>   of what he had eaten to that of his waste products, the latter being
>   considerably smaller because for every eight pounds of food he ate, he
>   excreted only 3 pounds of waste.

Comment: Rather than supplying just a link, you really should explain your answer.

Answer (score 4):

You exhale about 0.4 pounds of carbon atoms each day, which you can't keep track of. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2605/how-does-mass-leave-the-body-when-you-lose-weight .

Comment: This is excellent, but I'm awarding the answer to the fellow who actually linked an empirical study that was done :O

Answer (score 1):

If you weighed all of your food during a week you would be normal.

If you weighted all of your collected excrement, urine and sweat<sup>*</sup> you have bigger issues than a *physical* fitness regime could help with.

<sup>* "And blood, don't forget blood"</sup>
[image]