# Can breathing more often over the course of the day contribute to weight loss?

Tags: weight-loss, body-fat

related to an older question here: [If I were to weigh all the food and water I take in, and weigh all of the human waste I produced could that be used to determine weight gain or loss?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/23913/32002)

the tl;dr of that article is that we lose a ton of weight exhaling carbon dioxide each day.

my question: if you were to make a conscious effort to breathe more often while you are awake, would it speed up the production of carbon dioxide and thus make you lose weight faster?

I know breathing rate generally increases during exercise as blood flow increases, which might contribute to weight loss during exercise, but would the opposite also be true where breathing faster increases blood flow?

also does anyone know any possible consequences this could have on the body?

sorry if this idea is super far out in left field, I'm a bit new to the fitness field, and I'm trying to explore a bit to get my bearings, and this is a thought that came to mind.

Comment: You should ask in a biology board how the human metabolism work. You know have two pieces of information that you might put together to another false conclusion. Better learn how it works from people that know it

Comment: There is a Ted talk that would suggest this is the case.  It talks about how fat leaves our body, and about 80-85% leave through exhaling.

Answer (score 7):

No, it wouldn't. Hyperventilation doesn't cause the body to produce more carbon dioxide, instead it just reduces the amount of CO2 in the blood, which reduces the amount of CO2 passed in each breath.

So if you're breathing twice as frequently as normal, each breath will release half the normal amount of CO2.